# Is there a way to override CKEditor's config file for each instance of the editor?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ckeditor, content-management-system

I have a global size and height set

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
{
  config.height = '400px';
  config.width = '600px';
  ...
```

And I would like to change this height and width for only one instance of the editor on a seperate page. Has anyone else accomplished this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes.  When you create the editor on the page, you can override

```
CKEDITOR.replace(editorName, {
            height: 448,
            width: 448,
            customConfig: '/path/to/yourconfig.js'
});
```

In fact as a [performance recommendation](http://ckeditor.com/blog/CKEditor_Loading_performance_details) you can put all the configuration options here and save the loading of the config file separately.  You might do this in a shared JavaScript file of your own, parametrized to override specific values for a page.

**UPDATE** in response to comment

A separate config file can be used like any other setting (look above with customConfig.  If you don't want any [custom configs](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#constructor) loaded use

```
customConfig: ''
```

Comment: Thanks Dove! Really appreciate it!

Comment: in response to performance recommendation, I tried that, but my syntax was wrong I guess? CKEDITOR.replace(editorName, config) where config was a file alongside config.js called otherConfig.js .

Comment: Does this work with multiple instances on the CKEditor on a page?  Seems that if you have multiple instances each with their own config, that the last created instance's config file is applied to all the other instances... Or am I just a moron :)

Comment: @nokturnal you can and I do have different configurations for multiple instances on the one page.  Quick sanity check from above would be adjusting width or height.

Comment: When I call replace it throws "Uncaught The editor instance "note1681" is already attached to the provided element." what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can resize editor on `instanceReady` event:

```
CKEDITOR.on 'instanceReady', (evt) ->
  setCustomHeight(evt.editor)

setCustomHeight = (editor) ->
  height = $(editor.element.$).attr('height')
  return unless height

  editor.resize('100%', height)
```

Now you have to specify height attribute on the textarea for which you want to have custom height:

`<textarea id="my-editor" height="250"></textrarea>`