# How to load new editorConfig for inline editor at run-time?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I have run the [Toolbar Configurator](https://ckeditor.com/latest/samples/toolbarconfigurator/index.html#basic) to remove some unwanted items from the toolbar.  I can get the toolbar config, which consists of some javascript code which starts like this:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    config.toolbarGroups = [
```

However, it is unclear to me how to use this when instantiating a specific editor instead of using it globally.  I have tried pasting this in my code before I instantiate the editor in question, but it shows the full toolbar with the unwanted items.  I am also making some other `CKEDITOR.config` and `CKEDITOR.on` assignments at this time which do work.

I also tried modifying the configuration code within the function by changing the `config` to `editor.config` (where editor comes from the "editor" field of the event passed to the callback) and initializing it in the callback of `CKEDITOR.on("instanceReady")` but that also did not work.

Then I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987922/is-there-a-way-to-override-ckeditors-config-file-for-each-instance-of-the-edito) and tried using the replace function like so:

```
CKEDITOR.on("instanceReady", function(evt) {
    ...
    CKEDITOR.replace(evt.editor.name, {
        toolbarGroups: [
           ...
        ],

        removeButtons: "..."
    })
    ...
```

This also doesn't work!

Then I tried pasting the raw config from the configurator into a new file "config2.js" in my ckeditor directory on the server [as this page suggests should work](https://ckeditor.com/old//forums/CKEditor/Different-Toolbars-for-different-Editor-Instances), and changing the replace call to:

```
CKEDITOR.replace(evt.editor.name, {
    customConfig: "config2.js"
})
```

This doesn't work, even if I replace the string with "../ckeditor/config2.js". Looking at the network requests I see it doesn't even try requesting "config2.js" from anywhere.

If it makes any difference, I am starting the editor using CKEDITOR.inline(div) so as far as I know I have to perform the configuration in an event callback.

I also tried calling the replace function from the "instanceCreated" callback - this resulted in an infinite loop / max recursion exceeded error.  I also tried it in the "instanceLoaded" event, also without effect.

Update:
I just noticed in the console that when it tries to call replace it throws this error:

```
Uncaught The editor instance "note1681" is already attached to the provided element.
```

So it seems I am doing something incorrectly with replace.

Comment: Check how editor is build on those examples [here](https://sdk.ckeditor.com/index.html)
and also helpful might be searching through [old samples here](https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.7.3/full-all/samples/old/)

There is plenty of examples how editor is configured with different ways. Generally you need to provide toolbar configuration in moment when you initialise the editor, so when you call CKEDITOR.replace, CKEDITOR.inline method.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's impossible to hide buttons(change toolbar) after you initialized instance. However, you can recreate you ckeditor with new toolbar. 
First, you need to destroy current instance, before creating new one.

`CKEDITOR.instances.note1681.destroy();
 CKEDITOR.replace('note1681');`

For fast switching toolbar, i recommend use custom variable in configuration file.

Add in ckeditor/config.js your toolbar version

```
editor.my_toolbar  = [['Sourcedialog','Cut','Copy']];
```

Init ckeditor with it

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'note1681', { toolbar: my_toolbar })
```